# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props') - React Native

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, react-native

Im getting this type error when im trying to navigate to next view after getting json response.but my `this.props.navigator.push({id:'HomeCaseList')}` works well if i user out side of my json response getting method.can any one help me here.

`click event`

```
<MKButton
            style={{marginLeft:10, marginRight:10,marginTop:10,marginBottom:350,height:40, width:400}}
            backgroundColor={'#fff'}
            //shadowRadius={2}
            //shadowOffset={{width:0, height:2}}
            shadowOpacity={.7}
            shadowColor="black"
              onPress={
              //  navigator.push();

                this.loginToApp.bind(this)
              }>
```

`login function`

```
gotoNext() {
      fetch('http://url/login/', {
        credentials: 'same-origin',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          username: 'wasalaa',
          password: 'a',
        })
      }).then(function(response) {
      //console.log(response.headers.get('Content-Type'))
      //console.log(response.headers.get('Date'))
      //console.log(response.status)
      //console.log(response.statusText)
      //console.log('json',response
      //console.log(response.headers.get('JSESSIONID'))
      return response.json()
      }).then(function(json){
      console.log('login response',json)
      if(json.message_code === "SUCCESS"){
        console.log('user logged')
        this.props.navigator.push({
          id: 'HomeCaseList',
          //sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom,
        });
      }

      }).catch(function(err){
      console.log('error', err)
      })
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In callback `this` refers to global scope(*in browser it is `window` in node.js it is `global`, and if you use [`strict mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) this will be `undefined`*) and not for your component, you should set `this`

```
//....
.then(function(json) {
  if (json.message_code === "SUCCESS") {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      id: 'HomeCaseList',
      // sceneConfig: Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromBottom
    });
  }
}.bind(this))
 ^^^^^
// ....
```